# startActivityForResult - put Value to onActivityResult

Tags: android, bundle

I'm starting an Intent for choosing an Image from Gallery. My target is to put an Extra (an int value) to `onActivityResult`, but I can figure out how to do this.

The way I call the image chooser:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/jpg");
photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Intent photoResultIntent = Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Bild auswählen");
fragment.startActivityForResult(photoResultIntent, HorseFragment.PICK_IMAGE, bundle);
```

What I tried (with no success):

1. instantiating a new Bundle and give it to `startActivityForResult()` as third parameter
2. using photoResultIntent.putExtra...

How can I put a value to my target activity and retrieve it in `onActivityResult`? Can anyone explain it to me?

Thank you a lot for your time and your help!

Comment: you should put your extra for your main intent ( photoPickerIntent )

Comment: that doesn't work either... Isn't it possible to put a value to the target activity?

Comment: I didn't understand, the Activity in which you choose your Image is not from your application?  What does your `int` correspond?